# Refresh a MVC view page using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3

How to refresh a view page without refreshing page in jquery.

Here is my code..Please Help to resolve it

```
<html>
<head>
    <Title>Just A Test</Title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function ()
    {
    $('#load_me').load('samp.jsp').fadeIn("slow");
    }, 10000); // autorefresh the content of the div after
               //every 10000 milliseconds(10sec)
    </script>
 </head>
<body>
<div id="load_me"> <%@ include file="samp.jsp" %></div>
</body>
/html>
```

Comment: use javascript:timedRefresh(4000); where you want refresh.

Comment: why not just location.Reload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you forgot to execute your function 'auto_refresh();' !

**try this:**

```
<html>
<head>
   <Title>Just A Test</Title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(function (){
          $('#load_me').load('samp.jsp').fadeIn("slow");
         }, 10000); // auto refresh the content of the div after
                    // every 10000 milliseconds(10sec)
     auto_refresh();
    </script>
 </head>
<body>
<div id="load_me"> <%@ include file="samp.jsp" %></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't need to call auto_refresh to execute the function, auto_refresh is a reference which you can use to stop execution of function called through  setInterval()  for eg. clearInterval(auto_refresh) working example here http://jsfiddle.net/Df5DG/